"Couldn't load PyQGIS" when launching QGIS with Anaconda
I'm trying to install QGIS in a new environment on Anaconda.
Here is the command I used:
conda install -c conda-forge qgis

But it seems like Python couldn't work with this QGIS here when I launch QGIS in cmd:

Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "D:\anaconda3/envs/GIS/Library/./python\qgis\gui\__init__.py", line
25, in 
    from qgis._gui import *
RuntimeError: qgis._gui cannot import type '����' from PyQt5.QtCore


Python version:
3.12.4 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jun 18 2024, 15:03:56) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
3.38.1-Grenoble 'Grenoble', exported

Python path:


Can you help me solve this problem?

Perhaps this guide will help you: https://aneto.pt/posts/tutorials/2024-05-11-create-easy-pyqgis-developement-environment-using-conda-and-vscode/

Eventually also this guide might be useful

Use older python version (3.10 or 3.9) for creating new environment, e.g.
conda create -n qgis -c conda-forge python=3.10
